# No output on webpage from the database

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, sql

When loading my home.php page it should print the data from the select the data from the database 'blog_post' onto the page. However the record gets inserted properly but no data is shown on the page. I have looked up various solutions on here and none of them have seemed to work.

I have looked at many questions on here similar to my problem. None of the answers have seemed to answer my issue. I had tried this using PDO which had worked but with tables, however I do not want to do it that way as it was also a bit much for what I was trying to achieve.

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT postTitle, postCont FROM blog_post WHERE 
blogid = ? ORDER BY blogid DESC");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $postTitle['postTitle']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($postTitle, $postCont);
$stmt->fetch();
if(!$postTitle){
    echo "<p align='center'>No Blog Currently Available!</p>";
} else {
    echo '<div>';
    echo '<h1>'.var_dump($postTitle).'</h1>';
    echo '<p>'.$postCont.'</p>';                
    echo '</div>';
}
```

I expect that when the data is added to the database via my admin.php page. It should then display the data onto home.php.

Comment: Are you sure that your database column `blogid` shold be compared with the bound value of `$postTitle`?

Comment: "no data is shown on the page" ...do you mean that you see the "No Blog Currently Available!" message, or that you literally see nothing at all? If the latter, please check if PHP crashed, and whether error reporting / logging is enabled. Then you might be able to see if an error occurred. I suspect you might have one because `$row` is not an array. As per the docs, [fetch()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php) can only return true, false or null. When you work with fetch(), you get the data by using bind_result, not by reading row arrays.

Comment: I see "No Blog Currently Available!" on the page, even though there is data in the database. When using an array before (forgot to post that in the question), it had another error (which is can't quite remember now). I believe it was something to do with being false.

Comment: Ok well like I said, that'll be because `$row` isn't an array. Probably a warning is being generated as well (but possibly suppressed). You've bound your output variables to $postTitle and $postCont, so use them. `echo '<h1>'.$postTitle.'</h1>';
echo '<p>'.$postCont.'</p>';`. I think you've got confused between the syntax you're using now and the syntax you can use when you [do it via get_result()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27585505/5947043)

Comment: P.S. Pay attention to the very first comment as well - unless you've named your variables very badly, you appear to have a mismatch which might lead to no results being returned anyway. It might even generate an error if $postTitle contains a string, since you've told the database to expect an integer.

Comment: I have managed to make some sort of development. However, now after reading what you have said, it no longers says "No Blog Currently Available!", it now ouputs 'Array' in <h1> where ```$postTitle``` should be.

Comment: That doesn't really make sense, based on the code above. Try this (just for testing): `echo '<h1>'.var_dump($postTitle).'</h1>';` then we can see exactly what is in there. P.S. I saw your comment by chance since this question was still open in another tag. If you want to ensure I see your comments, please tag my username in your comment using @, e.g. @ADyson

Comment: P.S. Did you deal with the issue in the first comment or not? It's unclear if you've checked that out before commenting again?

Comment: array(1) { ["postTitle"]=> &NULL } This is what is shown & Yes I have changed it from an integer to a string. @ADyson

Comment: "I have changed it from an integer to a string" ...but what value are you actually passing to the database via the $postTitle variable? surely in your database `blogid` is an integer? And $postTitle presumably contains a string with the title of your post? So how are you expecting these two things to ever be equal? I'm quite sure that will be why your title is null afterwards. You need to send the blog ID to the database to get an exact match to the right row.

Comment: I have put the updated code onto the post above. @ADyson

Comment: As for the Array thing, having read https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php I can see (from the examples) that it will create an array of values from all the rows returned for each column (even if only one row was returned - or none). So if you only ever expect one row then `echo '<h1>'.$postTitle[0].'</h1>'; echo '<p>'.$postCont[0].'</p>';` will work (assuming the values aren't null). If you expect multiple rows then you'd need a loop.

Answer (score 2):

`fetch` returns Boolean not an array. You've bound two variables, so use them:

```
$stmt->bind_result($postTitle, $postCont);
$stmt->fetch();
if(!$postTitle){
    echo "<p align='center'>No Blog Currently Available!</p>";
} else {
    echo '<div>';
    echo '<h1>'.$postTitle.'</h1>';
    echo '<p>'.$postCont.'</p>';                
    echo '</div>';
}
```